# Why is my C++ program running fine with the debugger but not without it?

Tags: c++, vector, initialization, clion

I am trying to recreate the vector class with its basic functions, but my program keeps exiting halfway through the operations. When I run the debugger it fully executes just fine. Here is what my vector class looks like:

```
template<class T>
class Vector {
    T* _array;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;


public:
    Vector() : _size(0), _capacity(8), _array(new T[_capacity]) { }
    ~Vector() { delete[] _array; }

    void _grow() {
        T* tmp = _array;
        size_t old_cap = _capacity;
        _capacity *= 2;
        _array = new T[_capacity];
        for (size_t i = 0; i < old_cap; i++) {
            _array[i] = tmp[i];
        }
        delete[] tmp;
    }

    void push_back(T const& item) {
        if (_size == _capacity) { _grow(); }
        _array[_size++] = item;
    }

    void pop_back() {
        _size--;
    }

    void insert(T item, int position) {
        // implement insert here
        for (int i = position; i < _size-1; i++) {
            _array[i+1] = _array[i];
        }
        _size++;
        if (_size == _capacity) {
            _grow();
        }
        _array[position] = item;
    }

    void remove(int position) {
        // implement remove here
        for (int i = position; i < _size-1; i++) {
            _array[i] = _array[i+1];
        }
        _size--;
    }

    T& operator[](int index) {
        // implement operator[] here
        return _array[index];
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return _size;
    }

    void clear() {
        // implement clear here
        _size = 0;
    }
};
```

And here is the code actually initializes the class object and calls its member functions:

```
template<class T>
void noisy_push_back(Vector<T>& vector, T item) {
    vector.push_back(item);
    std::cout << "vector.push_back(" << item << ')' << std::endl;
}

template<class T>
void print_vector(Vector<T>& vector) {
    std::cout << "vector =";
    for (int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << ' ' << vector[i];
    }
}

void test1() {
    std::cout << "--- Test 1 output ---\n" << std::endl;

    Vector<std::string> vector;

    noisy_push_back<std::string>(vector, "wonder");
    noisy_push_back<std::string>(vector, "yak");
    print_vector(vector);

    std::cout << std::endl;
    noisy_push_back<std::string>(vector, "bookshelf");
    noisy_push_back<std::string>(vector, "euphoria");
    print_vector(vector);
}
```

When I run the program normally, it adds "wonder" and "yak" and then prints the vector just fine. When it tries to `push_back("bookshelf")` it exits with `Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`

Any ideas?

I tried printing out the vector size right before it exits and it was as expected: `size() = 2`
Also when I try to run the debugger everything looks normal and the program runs just fine. I am using CLion by the way.

Comment: `0xC0000005` is an access violation. You are accessing memory you should not be

Comment: A common difference between debug and release versions is initialization.  Many debuggers will initialize variables for you.  In release mode, you get whatever is in memory, it doesn't initialize for you.

Comment: Some bugs can produce intermittent and varied symptoms depending on other details. Running under the debugger shifts some of those details around, so can change whether those bugs produce visible symptoms and what those symptoms are.

Comment: Besides the problem you are asking about, your `Vector` class is likely to cause a lot of problems later because it doesn't follow the [Rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). At the very least, you need to define a copy constructor and copy assignment operator.

Comment: `int main() { Vector<std::string> vector; Vector<std::string> vector2 = vector; }` This simple code causes a double-free error when `main` terminates.  This is because your `Vector` class, as mentioned, fails to follow the [rule of 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).  Go to that link, and scroll down to the **Managing resources** section -- you see the code there has the same issues as your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your compiler should warn you about this; if it does not, turn up your warnings!

```
 Vector() : _size(0), _capacity(8), _array(new T[_capacity])
```

You are trying to initialize your `_array` last, however, since your variables are declared in the order of:

```
    T* _array;
    size_t _size;
    size_t _capacity;
```

Then `_array` will be initialized first. `_capacity` will be indeterminate at the time of initialization, thus you have Undefined Behaviour.

Comment: Now that the OP has fixed his immediate problem, he should take a look at function `insert`.  It may need to `_grow()` the array BEFORE moving any elements. It also needs to run its loop in REVERSE, so that elements are not overwritten in the process of shifting them rightwards. Functions `pop_back`, `remove`, and `insert` should check their subscript argument (or the size of the array) before operating. To avoid invalidating a `Vector` object when operator `new` fails, function `_grow` should call `new` BEFORE modifying `_capacity` or `_array`. And, don't forget the "Rule of 3/5/0!"

Answer (score -1):

You should learn to use tools. First enable warnings. Then use address sanitizer to find memory errors:
https://godbolt.org/z/r5EjWoce8

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000018 at pc 0x000000406672 bp 0x7ffc3d36ce50 sp 0x7ffc3d36ce48
READ of size 8 at 0x602000000018 thread T0
    #0 0x406671 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:234
    #1 0x406671 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_is_local() const /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:275
    #2 0x406671 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::capacity() const /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:1170
    #3 0x406671 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.tcc:279
    #4 0x4087f1 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::assign(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:1607
    #5 0x4087f1 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator=(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:813
    #6 0x4087f1 in Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::push_back(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&) /app/example.cpp:27
    #7 0x4087f1 in void noisy_push_back<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >(Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) /app/example.cpp:71
    #8 0x403304 in test1() /app/example.cpp:88
    #9 0x402328 in main /app/example.cpp:100
    #10 0x7f2a53229d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #11 0x7f2a53229e3f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29e3f) (BuildId: c289da5071a3399de893d2af81d6a30c62646e1e)
    #12 0x402384 in _start (/app/output.s+0x402384) (BuildId: d659454d1d76514eedee496e191fc29a836621ba)

0x602000000018 is located 0 bytes after 8-byte region [0x602000000010,0x602000000018)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f2a53ed1ce8 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xdcce8) (BuildId: 4508ebe68c8328f99c6a77c3715bff492eb1cfd5)
    #1 0x402f9e in Vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >::Vector() /app/example.cpp:11
    #2 0x402f9e in test1() /app/example.cpp:86

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.1.0/include/c++/13.1.0/bits/basic_string.h:234 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_data() const
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x601ffffffd80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601ffffffe00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601ffffffe80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601fffffff00: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x601fffffff80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x602000000000: fa fa 00[fa]fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000080: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000100: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000180: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000200: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x602000000280: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
==1==ABORTING
```

Note that stack frames 6-9 shows where problem is.

If you read compiler warning and address sanitizer report you should understand that reordering fields should resolve your problem:
https://godbolt.org/z/WEovKGn65

Comment: I see lots of fans of giving a fish instead teaching how to use fishing rod :(.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes may be because there is a leap of logic between "If you read the compiler warning" and "you should understand that ....". The answer can read as "the solution to your problem is to have already known how to fix it". Instructing to turn on warnings is good advice but "Then use address sanitizer to find memory errors." can feel like [Draw the rest of the owl](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/how-to-draw-an-owl) if you don't already know how to do it. Instructions on how to interpret the warning and address sanitizer output to find the problem would help complete the answer.

Comment: @MarekR This falls well short of "teaching how to fish."